# Convert a nested data structure to use a class object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following:

```
data = [
    {
        "user":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},
        "info":{"x":1,"y":2},
        "moreInfo":{"name":"johns12info"}
    },
    {
        "user":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},
        "info":{"x":2,"y":2},
        "moreInfo":{"name":"johns22info"}
    },
    {
        "user":{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Doe"},
        "info":{"x":2,"y":2},
        "moreInfo":{"name":"marys22info"}
    }
```

]

However, i wish for the user members to be objects of type User. So I wish to convert the above to the following:

```
data = [
    {
        "user":User({"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}),
        "info":{"x":1,"y":2},
        "moreInfo":{"name":"johns12info"}
    },
    {
        "user":User({"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}),
        "info":{"x":2,"y":2},
        "moreInfo":{"name":"johns22info"}
    },
    {
        "user":User({"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Doe"}),
        "info":{"x":2,"y":2},
        "moreInfo":{"name":"marys22info"}
    }
```

]

What javascript ES6 conversion can I use that is tidy and robust (the conversion should not explicitly mention `info` or `moreInfo`)? In python I would probably have used comprehensions to do this but Array comprehensions in javascript are non standard.

Comment: data = data.map(x=>{x.user = User(x.user); return x})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over data and update the property as `x.user=new User(x.user)`

Note: this will override existing array.

```js
function User(obj) {
  this.firstName = obj.firstName;
  this.lastName = obj.lastName;
  this.fullName = () => {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
  }
}

var data = [{ "user": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, "info": { "x": 1, "y": 2 }, "moreInfo": { "name": "johns12info" } }, { "user": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, "info": { "x": 2, "y": 2 }, "moreInfo": { "name": "johns22info" } }, { "user": { "firstName": "Mary", "lastName": "Doe" }, "info": { "x": 2, "y": 2 }, "moreInfo": { "name": "marys22info" } }];

data.forEach(x => {
  x.user = new User(x.user);
});

data.forEach(x=>{console.log(x.user.fullName())})
```

If you wish to create a new array, use `array.map`

```js
function User(obj) {
  this.firstName = obj.firstName;
  this.lastName = obj.lastName;
  this.fullName = () => {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
  }
}

var data = [{ "user": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, "info": { "x": 1, "y": 2 }, "moreInfo": { "name": "johns12info" } }, { "user": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, "info": { "x": 2, "y": 2 }, "moreInfo": { "name": "johns22info" } }, { "user": { "firstName": "Mary", "lastName": "Doe" }, "info": { "x": 2, "y": 2 }, "moreInfo": { "name": "marys22info" } }];

var pData = data.map(x => {
  x.user = new User(x.user);
  return x;
});

pData.forEach(x=>{console.log(x.user.fullName())})
```

Comment: Nice description.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a destructuring and iterate the data.

```js
function User({ firstName, lastName }){
    this.firstName = firstName,
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

var data = [{ user: { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }, info: { x: 1, y: 2 }, moreInfo: { name: "johns12info" } }, { user: { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }, info: { x: 2, y: 2 }, "moreInfo": { name: "johns22info" } }, { user: { firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Doe" }, info: { x: 2, y: 2 }, moreInfo: { name: "marys22info" } }];

data.forEach(o => o.user = new User(o.user));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```